# How to get object TextBlock from View and manipulate it in the ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I am using Caliburn.Micro in a WPF project with c#.

I wanted a way, like in android to find a "TextBlock" in a xaml view by it's "id" so that I can manipulate its properties.

I was thinking of doing something like this but for c#:

```
TextBlock textblock = (TextBlock ) myView.findViewById(R.id.myTextBlock);
```

so I can collapse and make it visible again.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlockId"
               Text="Incorrect user credentials. Forgot password, click here" 
               Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

Comment: From which class are you trying to manipulate the TextBlock?

Comment: It is a login page. So on a failed attempt I was going to un collapse a TextBlock "that would say forgot password click here". I was going to do this inside the ViewModel

Comment: You shouldn't be performing control manipulations inside the viewmodel. The view should be aware of the viewmodel. Not the other way around. If, for example, you had a boolean property named IsBadLogin, you could bind the visibility of the TextBlock to that property and use a BooleanToVisibilityConverter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MVVM Approach**

ViewModel

```
class MyViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private bool _isBadLogin;

    public bool IsBadLogin
    {
        get => _isBadLogin;
        set => Set(ref _isBadLogin, value);
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlockId"
           Text="Incorrect user credentials. Forgot password, click here" 
           Visibility="{Binding IsBadLogin, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}"/>
```

Comment: For anyone using caliburn.Micro you don't need to extend PropertyChangedBase because Screen inherits PropertyChangedBase.

Comment: Always been a Prism/MVVMLight guy :)